# Make div with position absolute scrolleable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a chat HTML template. But I'm having some problems to make scrolleable the messages area.

My structure is like this:

**Chat header**: to the top with the title of the chat or name person.
**Chat input message**: to the bottom you can write.
**Chat visible area**: total height - (chat header height + chat input message height).
**Messages:** Must increment it height but always be at the bottom of the chat visible area, to read the last message.

All this structure lives with other html elements, is not fullscreen.

[image]

My HTML structure is like this:

```
<div id="chat-1" class="chat-ventana">
    <div class="chat-header">
        <h4>Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-mensajes-contenedor">
        <div class="chat-mensajes-contenedor-general">
            <div class="mensaje-contenedor">
                <!-- messages content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-textarea">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
        <a href="#" class="mensaje-enviar"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks is this:

```
.chat-container {
  height: 70vh;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.chat-ventana {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
}

.chat-ventana, .chat-mensajes-contenedor {
  height: 100%;
}

.chat-mensajes-contenedor, .chat-mensajes-contenedor-general {
  padding: 15px 15px 20px 15px;
}

.chat-header {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.chat-mensajes-contenedor {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 400px;
}

.chat-mensajes-contenedor-general {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.chat-ventana, .chat-mensajes-contenedor {
  height: 100%;
}

.chat-mensajes-contenedor {
  height: calc(100% - 46px);
}

.chat-mensajes-contenedor, .chat-mensajes-contenedor-general {
  padding: 66px 20px 25px 20px;
}

.chat-textarea {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.chat-textarea .form-control {
  resize: none;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

I see if I set `.chat-mensajes-contenedor-general` to `position: relative;` it becomes scrolleable but I can't position it to the bottom.

Comment: Tell me if this is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/gLahjk5z/. Not entirely sure if I understand your question.

Comment: @theblindprophet Actually I need that the message always be at the bottom. Like the natural behavior of a chat. That the last message always be at the bottom of the visible area and make scroll to the top.

Comment: Ahh, so that is what you want except you want the text to be already scrolled to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what you're after.

And it's probably obvious but since you didn't say we can't use javascript you can of course employ a little of it (using jQuery in the case below) to achieve the same end result:

[**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/ye199qe1/)**]

```
function returnScrollHeight() {
    return this.scrollHeight;
}

$('.chat-mensajes-contenedor').scrollTop(returnScrollHeight);

$('textarea.form-control').on('keyup', function (e) {
      if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 13) {
        $('.mensaje-contenedor').append('<div class="line">' + this.value + '</div>');

        $('.chat-mensajes-contenedor').scrollTop(returnScrollHeight);

        this.value = '';
    }
});
```

I couldn't come up with a non-js solution in the brief time I tried. Hopefully someone else will come along and give the pure html/css answer.

Comment: Actually JQuery works for me but a HTML/CSS answer would be nice! I want implement this in HTML website and in Ionic, so for the web JQuery works (Ionic I don't know I'm very new in that).

Your jsfiddle help me a lot but just one question: what if I have few content like the beginning of a conversation? The content still being at the top of the window.

Comment: Maybe add a padding-top to .mensaje-contenedor [see this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/ye199qe1/2/) I'm not yet fully up to date with flexbox but if you're okay with using that the other answer might be a better option.

Comment: I need to give IE support, so flexbox is not an option. But thanks! This answer solve the basic problem I had.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gLahjk5z/3/

I changed the position styles to `position: relative` and altered some of your height elements.

I then added this Jquery function to run on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bottom = $(".mensaje-contenedor").height();
    $(".chat-mensajes-contenedor").scrollTop(bottom);
})
```

To make messages always appear at the bottom use this CSS:

```
.chat-mensajes-contenedor-general {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.mensaje-contenedor {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: I'ven watched you jsfiddle, help me a lot. But just one question what if a have less content than the `.mensaje-contenedor` height? The content is not to the bottom. For example the very beginning of a chat, example two messages. Check my jsfiddle update https://jsfiddle.net/JMarqz/gLahjk5z/2/ Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer and the jquery to allow for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not 100% sure to use flexbox because I need to give support for IE. But thanks, it helps me a lot.